# How do I add one-pixel border to a 'div' whose width is a percentage?

Tags: css

I have [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tara_irvine/DZLTJ/1/) which explains my problem.

I want the menu items along the top to be 20% of the window, but I also want them to have a one-pixel right border.

As you can see it's slightly out, this is very noticeable.

```
----------------------------------------------
| menu 1 | menu 2 | menu 3 | menu 4 | menu 5 |
----------------------------------------------
|          row one needs to be same          |
----------------------------------------------
```

I don't think a percentage border would work, because then it wouldn't be consistent with different window sizes.

How can I can accomplish this?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me.  The fifth menu item wraps onto a second line.

Comment: Me too, but at higher widths it is fine.  The problem I see is more to do with 1px + 20% + 1px + 20% + 1px + 20% + 1px + 20% + 1px + 20% + 1px > 100%.  That is why most times I design my site for a minimum screen width and then center all the content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use CSS `box-sizing` for this:

Like this:

```
#nav_1232938 li, .row {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: can't believe that this answer exists! I thought floats + borders > borders = BUG, reputation++

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a project where I had to do the same thing. Although box-sizing is probably the best answer, I decided to use generated *:after* elements (because of some issues specific to my project).

I set the *li*'s (width + padding) x number of *li*'s to equal 100%, then absolute positioned 12 pixels width, 100% height *li:after* elements to *top:0*, *right:-6px;* of each li. *Li:last-child* was floated right, so that it always lines up flush with the boxes beneath (browsers calculate fractional pixel remainders from percentages differently so sometimes you have a space on the far right of your floated elements, even if the elements' width adds up to 100%), and *li:last-child:after* was set to *display:none*.

Here's an edit of your JSFiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DZLTJ/12/

```css
.header {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #595858;
    padding: 54px 0;
        margin-bottom: 27px;
    position: relative;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    min-width: 755px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav_1232938 li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 18px 0;

    list-style: none;
    background-color: #585858;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 40px;
}

#nav_1232938 li:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    content: '';
    z-index: 10;
}

#nav_1232938 li:last-child {
    float: right;
}

#nav_1232938 li:last-child:after {
    display: none;
}

#nav_1232938 li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_1232938 {
    height: 75px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.header a{
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header h1 {
   position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    bottom: 18px;
}

.row .twelvecol {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.nav {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    z-index: 15000;
}
```

Notes: In my page, the padding set in % would never be smaller than the *:after* element's width set in  pixels, so the content box would never be obscured.

Box-sizing and *:after* are supported in all browsers post [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7), but *:last-child* actually has less support, no [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8). Like I said, box-sizing is probably a better choice, but in my case the absolutely positioned after element was a better fit—I thought it would be worth mentioning in case it was for anyone else too.

Comment: Years later: use box sizing.

Answer (score 1):

For the border, you can use

> ```
> outline: 1px solid black;
> ```

This works on all modern browsers, but not on [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) and [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7).