# CSS: Width in percentage and Borders

Tags: html, css, layout

I've defined widths of the containers in percentage. I'd like to add a border (3px on right side of a width), since container width is in % while the border width is in px, how can I adjust the width of the container?

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">...</div>
  <div class="right">...</div>
</div>

.wrap{
    width:100%;
}

.left{
    width:30%;
}

.right{
    width:70%;
}
```

I'd like to add 3px border on the right side of .left. For example:

```
.left{
    width:30%;
    border:3px solid #000;
}
```

Since I have defined width in the %, what is the best way to re-adjust the width of the .left. I can roughly decrease the width to 29%, but I want to do precisely.

Comment: adding *padding* to the container? Note that you should remove *width: 100%* then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add 1px border to a div whose width is a percentage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278523/how-do-i-add-1px-border-to-a-div-whose-width-is-a-percentage)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use the `box-sizing: border-box` property. It modifies the behaviour of the box model to treat padding and border as part of the total width of the element (not margins, however). This means that the set width or height of the element *includes* dimensions set for the padding and border. In your case, that would mean the element's width and it's border's width would consume 30% of the available space.

[image: CSS box model]

Support for it isn't perfect, however vendor prefixes will catch most if not all modern browsers:

```
.left {
    width: 30%;
    border: 3px solid #000;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

More information can be found on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) and [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html).

[According to Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t49), using the 3 vendor prefixes above (`-moz-`, `-webkit-` and `-ms-`), you get support for all browsers, even IE8.

Comment: why on earth isn't this the default behaviour

Comment: "All browsers" mentioned above means this: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box

- That is, no IE6 and IE7.

Comment: @Emil They're not really worth supporting as of 2014, unless there's a good business reason to do so

Comment: @Bojangles: I just wanted to make sure that people didn't miss the "unless" there.

Comment: Since edits need to be at least six characters long, I'm posting this as a comment: The MDN link currently points to 404 since the links are case-sensitive. `/En/` should be changed to `/en/` to avoid the 404.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest cross-browser way is to NOT set the border on the outer divs, and instead set it on a NEW div inside `.left`. Simple, and works well.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit tricky but check out this post on a way to get around it:

- [Percentage Plus Pixel Sizing](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/outside.html) (and [Example](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/plus.html))
- [Box Sizing on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) (and [Example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/BoxSizing/))

The [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) property may also be of interest to you, check this out:

- [How do I add 1px border to a div whose width is a percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278523/how-do-i-add-1px-border-to-a-div-whose-width-is-a-percentage/9288403)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ended up adding an outer div with a padding of the size that I wanted the original margin to be, and width 100%. That allowed me to set the inner div width to 100%, fitting entirely inside the padding (that would work as the previous margin I had set)

Answer (score -2):

Just change `px` to `vw` like

```
border-width: 10px;
```

to

```
border-width: 10vw;
```

Its do whats percentage do....

Comment: vw and vh don't do what percentages do. They're viewport units, and they're based off of the width of the viewport, ignoring elements within the viewport.