# floating two div tags that equal 100% width moves second div to new line

Tags: html, css

Newbie to everything.

I have two div tags, the first has a width of 80% and the second a width of 20%. 80%+20%=100% but the second div moves to the next line.

The objective is to use the whole line without moving to the second.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.border {
border-style: dotted;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="border" style="width: 80%;">thing</div>
<div class="border" style="width: 20%; float: left;">other thing</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070071/css-width-in-percentage-and-borders

Comment: You can float both divs to the left

Comment: I think it is. but i still don't know how to keep the dotted border D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

css code:

```
.table_formate {
  display:flex;
  width:100%
}
.border {
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table_formate">
  <div class="border" style="width: 80%; float: left; background: #dd0d0d;">thing</div>
  <div class="border" style="width: 20%; float: left; background: #4abdac;">other thing</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/taLytmbs/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider your border  with your width. The border adds to the width making the width value increase. You would have to reduce the width size for this to be possible

```css
.border {
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" style="width: 80%; float: left; background: #dd0d0d;">thing</div>
<div class="border" style="width: 20%; float: left; background: #4abdac;">other thing</div><br>

<div style="width: 80%; float: left; background: #dd0d0d;">thing</div>
<div style="width: 20%; float: left; background: #4abdac;">other thing</div><br>

<div class="border" style="width: 79%; float: left; background: #dd0d0d;">thing</div>
<div class="border" style="width: 19%; float: left; background: #4abdac;">other thing</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to put the border -1px inside so that it won't count?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<div class="border" style="width: 80%; float: left;">thing</div>
<div class="border" style="width: 20%; float: left;">other thing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to keep in mind is that block level elements, such as your div, always extend to the left and right edge of the page. When you set a width, you are setting the width of the content, not the [block context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting) as it's called. To do what you wish, you would need to float, or otherwise reposition, the first div so it does not occcupy the full width.

Also keep in mind that `border` is outside the width of content. And you must keep in mind padding and margin. Margin is added to the body on almost all graphical browsers, though this doesn't play into your problem.

So, your width is set to 80% and 20% of the parent element. The parent element is the body so we're OK here but you have a border. That border makes the total width of your content extend beyond the body by 2px; one px for each side of the div elements.

If you remove the borders and float the first div, you will accomplish what you want.

As an alternative, you can leave the borders in and make one or both of your div elements slightly smaller to accommodate the border.

To answer your question in a comment:

```
div { width: calc(80% - 2px); }
```

Note the "2px" as it's one px for each side of the div element. Maintain the spaces in the formula for this to work.

EDIT: Just noticed that the width of "dotted" as a border is larger than 1px. You'll need to set the minus value in the formula to accommodate whatever the width of the border is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing:border-box;` to keep border in the count of the width of element :

See below snippet

```css
.border {
    border-style: dotted;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="border" style="width: 80%; float: left; background: #dd0d0d;">thing</div>
<div class="border" style="width: 20%; float: left; background: #4abdac;">other thing</div><br>
```