# Whats the meaning of giving css “width:30%” to <aside> tag? We can keep <section> tag and give same css to that <section> tag. What is the different?

Tags: html, css

What is the meaning of giving css “width:30%” to  tag? We can keep  tag instead of  and we can also give same css to that  tag. What is the different in between this two things?

[section vs aside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHLr.png)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: Width in percentage and Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070071/css-width-in-percentage-and-borders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`section` and `aside` are two different types of semantic elements.  While technically you're correct and we can make them both `section`s, an `aside` element would indicate content more like a sidebar or inset, rather than another primary story in the page.  Think of a magazine article with a pull quote or a feature sidebar, rather than a page that has two full articles on it.

There's no functional difference in the code itself, since both `section` and `aside` function identically to `div`.  This is for accessibility and semantic organization.